# Neo4j HA performance

Tags: neo4j

I'm having big problems with performance in Neo4j. I have a HA cluster with 3 machines, and the write server has four processors and 8 GB of RAM. With less than 100 thousand nodes, the CPU is 80%, and average response time of 10 seconds.

I did a test with no HA machine and only one processor, the same database, same location. The response was less than 1 second.

Does anyone know why the Neo4j have this problem in HA mode?

Thanks

Comment: The performance problem still continues, though not very serious. Was a problem in load balancing. It seems that now, the system supports a few dozen people.

Answer (score 4):

For Neo4j Enterprise you may want to contact your support reference at NeoTechnology.

Also, you may want to provide server configuration, neo4j configuration, logs messages and the query/code used for the queries in order to get help.

Comment: I followed some spent as increasing heap of jvm for 2G (
wrapper.java.maxmemory = 2000), use the UseParallelGC (wrapper.java.additional = -XX: + UseParallelGC) and increase the limit of files that can be opened in linux. With that, I managed to reduce the response time from 10 to 3 seconds. If I increase the hardware can reduce more.

However, I am in doubt whether this excessive consumption of hardware in Neo4j is common. And even with the idle machine Neo4j still using more than 80% of CPU. Look: http://snag.gy/D69mb.jpg

Hugs

Answer (score 0):

Even I am facing the same problem. noHA is performing well than Neo4jHA. But I think Neo4jHA scales for more simultaneous queries than no HA machine. This advantage we can make use